# Is there a performance hit for Django tags using takes_context?

Tags: django, performance, templates, render, nodes

I sometimes access the context by supplying 'takes_context=True' for Django tags; Usually to acess the request.

But are there performance implications.

My mental model of how templates worke is that the tag function assembles the nodes representing the template, and that thereafter these nodes can render content without recreating the node, or reparsing the template.

But surely, if the tag function can be made to return different nodes, depending on
Something in the context, then the nodes will have to be recreated everytime the context is different (I.E every time).

Either that, or you are stuck with what nodes you get first time round, in which case you shouldn't return nodes based on anything in the context (in which case, what's the point?).

Can someone clear this up for me? I' using Django 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes are created when a template is loaded. When it's rendered, context is simply passed to the  Node's render method. The only difference `simple_tag`'s `takes_context` argument makes is making the resulting `Node.render` code pass context along to your function. So no, there are no performance implications to using `takes_context`.

Comment: Does this mean all defined node classes are created? Even if no tags use it?

Comment: *Classes* are created when modules containing them are loaded. As far as I'm aware it happens when `{% load xxx %}` is encountered when parsing a template. Node *instances* are created when the corresponding tag is encountered during template loading/parsing.

Comment: I assume the instance is only created if the tag uses that node though?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "tag uses that node"? A tag always uses it's own node. If you meant "only if the template uses that tag" then yes, that is true.

Comment: I mean if the tag is of the form "if X then return SomeNodeA() else return SomeNodeB()". A tag may conditionally return any node; I assume the node is only instanciated the first time it is actually used?

Comment: Actually you can't do that with `simple_tag`. `simple_tag` creates its own node instance (one per each occurrence of the tag in template) that calls your function at render time. If you are implementing the tag without `simple_tag` shortcut, using a compilation function and explicit node definition the node(s) will be instantiated every time the compilation function is called, which is every time your tag is encountered during template loading. In either case there will be exactly as many node instances as there are tag occurrences in the template.

Comment: Yes, this is how I'm using tags, So is there a performace hit, or are instanciations fairly cheap?

Comment: It's cheap and it's how every tag in Django works. Django's template system isn't the fastest out there but as long as it works for you overall writing custom tags that way won't spoil the performance.